# ¿Como subir imagenes al sql server desde el objeto dictionary en C#?

Tags: c#

Tengo un código formulado en c# y quiero saber como subir una imagen a través del objeto Dictionary,

En mi código intento pasar la imagen al dictionary pero no consigo pasarlo

Agradecería alguna sugerencia o ayuda cuanto antes.

Gracias, Saludos

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]! Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y así ganar tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/84/informed). Lee [ask] y [¿sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) para aprender a realizar una buena pregunta. En tu caso, sería muy interesante saber que has probado para no sugerir cosas que ya has intentado. Si tienes algún código intentando resolver el problema, te recomiendo que edites tu pregunta y lo añadas. Un saludo y bienvenido de nuevo

Comment: Creo que una de las mejores practicas a la hora de guardar fotos en BBDD, es : **1)** Convertir la foto a binario ( Si es un tamaño pequeño , KB, por ejemplo) **2)** En lugar de pasar la foto , guardar la ruta de la imagen en formato cadena

Comment: Mencionas `en mi codigo`, podrias poner parte de este indicando porque no puedes asignar la imagen? hay algun mensaje de error?

Comment: Molts graçies ..